# How to recover from forgetting `repo start`?

Tags: repo

If I'm working on an Android change and I `git commit` but forget to `repo start` first, how do I recover from this so that I can `repo upload` my change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retroactively `repo start new-branch-name`:

```
git checkout -b new-branch-name
git branch --set-upstream-to aosp/master
repo upload .
```